# Understanding error in changing projection of SpatialPolygon (R)

Tags: r, sp

I am encountering an error I don't understand. I want to change the projection of a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame from +longlat to Mollweide or Robinson. For this I am trying to use spTransform(), but it returns the error:
"Error in .spTransform_Polygon(input[[i]], to_args = to_args, from_args = from_args,  :
failure in Polygons 125 Polygon 1 points 1:4:5"

My question: why am I getting this error?

Here is an MWE:

```
library(inlmisc)
library(sp)
projection <- "+proj=robin +datum=WGS84 +lat_0=0 +lon_0="

numlons <- 30
numlats <- 50

lat.df <- rep(seq(from=-90, to=90, length.out = numlats), each=numlons)
lon.df <- rep(seq(from=-180, to=180, length.out = numlons), times=numlats)

spobj <- as.vector(array(data=rnorm(n=50*30, mean=0, sd=1)))
spobj <- data.frame("dat"=spobj)
spobj <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=data.frame("longs"=c(lon.df), "lats"=lat.df), 
                                data=spobj, 
                                proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat"))
sp::gridded(spobj) <- TRUE
spobj <- as(spobj, "SpatialGridDataFrame")


### Change projection
spobj <- Grid2Polygons(grd=spobj, zcol="dat", cuts=100) # convert to SpatialPolygon
spobj <- spTransform(spobj, CRS(projection)) # change projection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid cells are going outside the valid range for lat-long data. When `spobj` is points (before `sp::gridded(spobj) <- TRUE`) it is this:

```
> spobj.pts
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 1500 
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 
variables   : 1
names       :               dat 
min values  : -3.85401447598915 
max values  :  3.65817120357171
```

but after `Grid2Polygons` it is this:

```
> spobj
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 1470 
extent      : -186.2069, 186.2069, -88.16327, 91.83673  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84
```

which has latitude past the north pole (+90) and longitudes past the anti-meridian (180 or -180). This is because the grid cells from `Grid2Polygons` are centred on the points. There's also fewer of them. It looks like its not bothered making grids from the bottom row:

[image]

So it looks like that's what `Grid2Polygons` does, and I'm not sure if that's what its meant to do or not (docs are vague) or what precisely you want to do to make polygon cells from your points. But the basic problem is that you cant project coordinates that aren't valid.